# how to format date in jquery template in mvc4 web api?

Tags: jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to format the date value in my mvc4 web api project.

`<p2>${JoinedDate}</p2>`

In database the value is like `2013-02-02 00:00:00.000`

Which i want to format as `Joined 1year ago`

that `1year` i want to calculate from `(databaseDate - TodaysDate)`

> how can I achieve this date difference in Jquery template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a javascript library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). Define this function:

```
function prettyFormatDate(date) {
    return moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS").fromNow();
}
```

and then use:

```
<p2>${prettyFormatDate(JoinedDate)}</p2>
```

`JoinedDate` should be as it comes from the DB. Javascript does the formatting.